# Graphite install error 0.10.0-alpha

Tags: python, django, graphite

I get the following error when starting Graphite-web using DJango.
0.9.15 works ok, but I am looking to use the new "mapSeries" function available in 0.10.x

Seems to be a missing import -

> ```
> Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi", line 46, in <module>
> import graphite.metrics.search  # noqa
> File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/metrics/search.py", line 6, in <module>
> from graphite.storage import is_pattern, match_entries
> ImportError: cannot import name match_entries
> ```

I'm not a python programer, but maybe the package is missing in the setup.py?

https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating `/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi` to the latest example version.
The 0.9.x version is not compatible with 0.10.x